# CListCtrl: change color of selected item

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to customize the color of the current selected item (row) in a `CListCtrl`-List.

```
void CMyList::OnCustomdraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    if (myList.GetItemState(pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec, LVIS_SELECTED) == LVIS_SELECTED)
    {
        pLVCD->nmcd.uItemState &= ~CDIS_SELECTED; // deselect item to enable custom coloring
        pLVCD->clrTextBk = SELECTION_BK_COLOR;
    }
}
```

The coloring itself works fine, but when I call `myList.GetFirstSelectedItemPosition()` it of course fails.

If I don't set the state to unselected, the coloring is overwritten.

What can I do? Do I have to overwrite another function than `OnCustomdraw`?

Comment: Have you checked this article? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra

Comment: You don't filter on the drawing stage, nor are you returning a value. If you need help with your **real** code, post your **real** code. In the meantime, have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761817.aspx) (all of the information applies to MFC as well; the Windows API reference is better quality, though).

Comment: I would implement a `CMFCListCtrl` derived class and override the `OnGetCellTextColor` method. Things are much easier this way than with custom draws.